# How to define a 2D array with `array('f')` similar syntax

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to do something similar to

```
d =  [[0]*5]*15)
```

but by using `array`, i.e. going from 1D `dd = array('f', [0]*5])` to something like `dd=array('f', [[0]*5]*15)` which of course does not work..

Comment: I don't think Python arrays can be 2-dimensional.

Comment: You could make a list of arrays. But an array element type can't be an array, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html